# Sequelize best way overwrite/update data

Tags: sequelize.js

I have table `categories` with field `title` also have the table `translations` with `fk` `categryId` and `region` and `title` for keep translations. Tables are associated.

I have a scenario of how translates comes from front-end to controller in the array like:

```
const translations = [

  { region: 'uk', title: 'title_in_uk' },
  { region: 'dk', title: 'title_in_dk' }

]
```

My goal updates translates with new ones. Probably the best way will override like:

`category.setTranslations(translations)`

but not sure or this way exist on at all.

Comment: Have you tried doing this and what is the result? Do translations update?

Answer (score -2):

In order to update a field you have to find its document first, then it may be easy to update it.
You can update field using code below

```
const model = await model.findOne({
    where: { title: 'title_in_uk' }
}).catch(err => {console.error('Error: ' + err)});
if (model) {
    const updateRecord = await model.update({
        // put the fields to be updated here containing the new values
    }).catch(err => {console.error('Error: ' + err)});
}
```

Your question is unclear... Plz let me know if you want something different